# Mysql script to update values using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code here that I use and whenever I run it, It runs without error but it does not update the values inside Mysql.

Kindly advice what's wrong.

Thanks.

Here's the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$loginuser = $_SESSION['result'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if ('$_POST[department]' == 'Shared') {
  //$sql="UPDATE `employee` SET `leavecount` = '$_POST[lbalance]', sickleave = 1 WHERE        `department` = '$_POST[department]'";
  $sql = "UPDATE `employee` SET `leavecount` = 6.44, sickleave = 5 WHERE `department` =       \'Shared\'";
echo ($sql);
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
echo "1 record added";

 }

header("location:manageemployeeleaves.php");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: remove quotes on `$_POST` on if `('$_POST[department]' == 'Shared')`

Comment: You will be wide open to SQL injection.  Please use prepared statements and parameterize your queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your current code, remove the quotes on `'$_POST[department]'`, as it is interpreted as a simple string. Consider this example:

```
<?php

session_start();
$loginuser = $_SESSION['result'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if($_POST['department'] == 'Shared') {
    $sql = "UPDATE `employee` SET `leavecount` = '6.44', sickleave = 5 WHERE `department` = 'Shared'";
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);    
header("Location: manageemployeeleaves.php");

?>
```

> Note: Since your are using **`mysqli`**, it is advisable to use **[`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)** instead of directly using your variables inside the query statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. If I may ask what is mysql injection by the way and how is it so bad?

Comment: @Patrick eto bro check mo, straight from the [**manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Sir Kevin may post akong bago baka po pwede pa check po kung tama yung gawa ko po.